# Normal for PEX-B fittings to rotate in tubing after crimping with copper crimp rings?

Tags: pex, fitting, crimp

Is it normal for a PEX-B fitting to be able to rotate in the tubing *after* crimping with copper crimp rings?

I’m using Apollo fittings, tubing, and copper crimp rings along with the IWISS iCrimp angle-head crimp tool. The go/no-go gauge seems to be able go halfway around the crimp ring still.
I’ve installed a couple dozen fittings already and either this wasn’t the case or I never noticed before. But now I’ve noticed with my last few crimps that I’ve made. I’m worried about leaks now.

Comment: To alleviate worries about leaks, do a pressure test with air before letting water in.

Comment: The fittings also rotate with pinch-clamp PEX rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, perfectly normal, and saves buying unions where transitioning to pipe-thread fittings.

Trust the go/no-go gauge on the crimp rings